# Using plain jquery / javascript to create a popup confirm box

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Here is the extract code of how to make a confim box when delete,

**For HTML part**
A link is to trigger JS code , but it will trigger the php code at same time

**For JS part**
popupbox is triggered

**For PHP part**
Process the sql query, it should be ok

**The problems are**...

1. I should use js to trigger the php page? But how can i let the php page know that which ListID i want to delete?
2. What should i put in the html link?
3. What if i want to include the list name in the popup box e.g. do you want to delete list A ,where list A is a variable already. The only thing is how can i append it to the popup box

Thank you

HTML

```
<a id="delete" href='delete.php?id=$set[ListID]'>Delete</a>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#delete").click(function() {
        // what should be add here? 
    });
});
```

PHP

```
//connection db
INSERT  INTO delete_list SELECT * FROM list WHERE ListID=?;    
INSERT  INTO delete_user_list SELECT * FROM user_list WHERE ListID=?;    
INSERT  INTO delete_require_attributes SELECT * FROM require_attributes WHERE ListID='2';    
INSERT  INTO delete_subscriber SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE ListID=?;    
INSERT  INTO delete_subscriber SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE ListID=?;    
DELETE FROM list WHERE ListID = '1'
```

**Sorry, I mess up the previous question as i found that the plugin i used in  last question does not work for me.**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using jquery / javascript to create a popup confirm box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788117/using-jquery-javascript-to-create-a-popup-confirm-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had done this by giving the id to the HTML element itself with [data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) ([HTML5 ref](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/)) sweet to use with jQuery.
After this you can do an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) optional to delete server-side in the database.

## Example

```
<a data-id="<?php echo $set[ListID]; ?>" class="delete-trigger" href='javascript:;'>Delete</a>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $("#delete-trigger").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://yoururl.com/delete.php?id=' + id,
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('deleted');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This ask the user whether to delete the list?

Comment: no this is just the execution of deleting a "list". to ask the user for confirm just do: `var booleanOfAnswer = confirm('your question');` - [help for this, here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

Answer (score 1):

html

```
<a class="delete" data-listname="<?php echo $set['ListName']?>" href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $set['ListID']?>">Delete</a>
```

js

```
$(function(){
  $(".delete").click(function() {

    return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete ' + $(this).data('listname') + '?');

 });
});
```

Comment: Won't this refresh the page, not allowing the js to be run? Also, shouldn't # be .

Comment: Sorry but I found that there is a flaw, if there are more than one link, one of them will not popup but directly go to the delete.php

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Need to replace an ID selector with CLASS selector. I changed my answer